# c# system.drawing calculate size of font for 1 character to fill a square image

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

If I have a System.Drawing.Bitmap with equal dimensions e.g. 100x100, 50x50 and I wanted to use this code to draw in a single character:

```
StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

font = new Font(_fontName, _fontSize, _fontStyle);

GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

path.AddString("A", font.FontFamily, (int)font.Style, font.Size, rect, stringFormat);
```

How would I go about calculating the value for _fontSize so that it fits tightly inside the dimensions of the image?

Comment: You`ll have to use a Fixed-width font for that, probably easier than calculating character widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphics.MeasureString function returns the size of a string of a given font. In a loop you can determine what font size fits best.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/403ezxd2.aspx

Answer (score -1):

its gonna help u:

```
    float fontsizeem = height;
    int charfits=0;int line=2;
    for (; charfits < captchastring.Length || line < 1 ; fontsizeem--)//font support style correct // color fix
    {
        graphic.MeasureString(captchastring, new Font(fontFamily, fontsizeem, fontstyle), new SizeF((float)width*0.6f, (float)height*0.6f), format, out charfits, out line);

    }

    fontsizeem *= graphic.DpiY /72 ; // this unit converting fucks me out :(((((((

    path.AddString(captchastring, fontFamily,(int) fontstyle,fontsizeem,rectangle, format);// --  size
```